# Set Color to Sudoku Cells

Tags: java, applet, sudoku

I have been working on a 9x9 sudoku applet and I want to set a color to every number. For example, if a cell contains "1" then the cell color should be blue. However, I am getting errors. I spent hours trying to figure out but every time it gives me different errors. Here's my code:

Thanks for the help!

```
    import java.applet.* ;
    import java.awt.* ;

    /**
    * Solves a sudoku puzzle by recursion and backtracking
    */
    public class SimplifiedSudoku extends Applet implements Runnable
    {
    /** The model */
    protected int model[ ][ ] ;

    /** The view */
    protected Button view[ ][ ] ;

    /** Creates the model and sets up the initial situation */
    protected void createModel()
    {
    model = new int[9][9] ;

// Clear all cells
for( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
  for( int col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
  model[row][col] = 0 ;

// Create the initial situation
model[0][0] = 9 ;
model[0][4] = 2 ;
model[0][6] = 7 ;
model[0][7] = 5 ;

model[1][0] = 6 ;
model[1][4] = 5 ;
model[1][7] = 4 ;

model[2][1] = 2 ;
model[2][3] = 4 ;
model[2][7] = 1 ;

model[3][0] = 2 ;
model[3][2] = 8 ;

model[4][1] = 7 ;
model[4][3] = 5 ;
model[4][5] = 9 ;
model[4][7] = 6 ;

model[5][6] = 4 ;
model[5][8] = 1 ;

model[6][1] = 1 ;
model[6][5] = 5 ;
model[6][7] = 8 ;

model[7][1] = 9 ;
model[7][4] = 7 ;
model[7][8] = 4 ;

model[8][1] = 8 ;
model[8][2] = 2 ;
model[8][4] = 4 ;
model[8][8] = 6 ;
 }

/** Creates an empty view */
protected void createView()
{
 setLayout( new GridLayout(9,9) ) ;

 view = new Button[9][9] ;
 // setBackground(Color.blue);

// something.setBackground(Color.red);

// Create an empty view
for( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
  for( int col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
{
  view[row][col]  = new Button() ;
  add( view[row][col] ) ;

}
}

  /** Updates the view from the model */
  protected void updateView()
  {
  for( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
  for( int col = 0; col < 9; col++ )

  if( model[row][col] != 0 )
  {
  view[row][col].setLabel( String.valueOf(model[row][col]) ) ;
  }
  else
  view[row][col].setLabel( "" ) ;
```

This is where I am getting error:

```
   if(model[0][0].equals("9"))
   {
     //[row][col].setColor(Color.red);
    // view[row][col].setBackground(Color.red);
    model[row][col].setBackground(Color.blue);
   }
}

/** This method is called by the browser when the applet is loaded */
public void init()
{
createModel() ;
createView() ;
updateView() ;
}

/** Checks if num is an acceptable value for the given row */
protected boolean checkRow( int row, int num )
 {
for( int col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
  if( model[row][col] == num )
  return false ;

  return true ;
 }

 /** Checks if num is an acceptable value for the given column */
 protected boolean checkCol( int col, int num )
 {
 for( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
  if( model[row][col] == num )
  return false ;

 return true ;
}

/** Checks if num is an acceptable value for the box around row and col */
protected boolean checkBox( int row, int col, int num )
{
row = (row / 3) * 3 ;
col = (col / 3) * 3 ;

for( int r = 0; r < 3; r++ )
  for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
  if( model[row+r][col+c] == num )
  return false ;

 return true ;
}

/** This method is called by the browser to start the applet */
public void start()
{
 // This statement will start the method 'run' to in a new thread
 (new Thread(this)).start() ;
 }

 /** The active part begins here */
 public void run()
 {
  try
  {
  // Let the observers see the initial position
  Thread.sleep( 100 ) ;

   // Start to solve the puzzle in the left upper corner
   solve( 0, 0 ) ;
   }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
    }
  }

  /** Recursive function to find a valid number for one single cell */
  public void solve( int row, int col ) throws Exception
 {
 // Throw an exception to stop the process if the puzzle is solved
 if( row > 8 )
  throw new Exception( "Solution found" ) ;

// If the cell is not empty, continue with the next cell
if( model[row][col] != 0 )
  next( row+1, col ) ;
else
{
  // Find a valid number for the empty cell
  for( int num = 1; num < 10; num++ )
  {
    if( checkRow(row,num) && checkCol(col,num) && checkBox(row,col,num) )
    {
      model[row][col] = num ;
      updateView() ;

      // Let the observer see it
      Thread.sleep( 100 ) ;

      // Delegate work on the next cell to a recursive call
      next( row+1, col) ;
    }
  }

  // No valid number was found, clean up and return to caller
  model[row][col] = 0 ;
  updateView() ;
}
}

/** Calls solve for the next cell */
public void next( int row, int col ) throws Exception
{
 if( col < 8 )
   solve( row+1, col ) ;
 else
   solve( row+1, 0 ) ;
 } 
}
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you could tell us what error(s) you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(model[0][0].equals("9"))`

model[0][0] is an `int`, not a `String`, thus:

`if(model[0][0] ==9)`

Comment: after doing that I get the following errors:


3 errors found:
File: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java  [line: 100]
Error: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java:100: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable row
location: class SimplifiedSudoku

File: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java  [line: 100]
Error: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java:100: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable col
location: class SimplifiedSudoku

File: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java  [line: 100]
Error: /CodeForProgram/SimplifiedSudoku.java:100: int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: `model[row][col].setBackground(Color.blue);` You need to put `{ ... }` for both of your loops around this, so that `row` and `col` are both in scope. Finally, model is an int[][]. You cannot call setBackground() or anything for that matter on an int